# Parser Error Message: There is not enough space on the disk azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are using a Azure Website to host a few sites/apps. We are currently using the "Shared Plan" which comes with 1Gb of storage of which the portal is telling me, we are currently using 15% of our allocated storage.

We have had no problems until recently when we have suddenly started to notice the following Yellow Screen of Death message on some pages:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: There is not enough space on the disk.
```

If we redeploy the error will sometimes go, but will shift itself to another "page" of the application. We even had the issue where page that didn't work yesterday, suddenly works today, meanwhile another page has broken (with no deployment in between).

We have been mindful of the Azure mindset and architecture and certainly aren't storing any "user generated" blobs server site (images, avatars etc) they are all pushed through to Azure Blob Storage. We are using an **HttpPostedFileBase** object directly through to **CloudBlockBlob**, so i *think* i'm confident our blobs aren't being stored on our server (and they certainly not turning up in our storage stats).

Any ideas of what else could be causing this issue? Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Update: Just restarted the website and at a quick glance most pages  appear to be working. I'm hoping that i don't have to restart the website every few days to a week. Any ideas?

Comment: Update 2: I've had comment from some MS folks that it may be a temp disk issue relating to the Shared Website (eg. Like Free). I have upgraded to a Basic Plan (Website VM) to see if the issue resolves.

Comment: Update 3: Since the upgrade to a Basic Plan (Website VM), I haven't seen the issue again.